# iOS: Programmatically called segue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using a SWRevealViewController segue that is called via method but isn't getting triggered. No errors are reported to the log, and it doesn't cause the app to hang or crash. I've checked the segue link on the storyboard and it has the correct class and identifier.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loadUrl];
    NSLog(loadUrl);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
            [mWebView loadRequest:request];         
        else if (error != nil) 
            NSLog(@"Error: %", error);}
    ];    
}

- (void)     captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput   
  didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects
            fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
     [metadataObjects
     enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(AVMetadataObject *obj,
                              NSUInteger idx,
                              BOOL *stop)
     {
         if ([obj isKindOfClass:
              [AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject class]])
         {
         // 3
             AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *code =
             (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject*)
             [_previewLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:obj];
         // 4
             Barcode * barcode = [Barcode processMetadataObject:code];

             for(NSString * str in self.allowedBarcodeTypes){
                 if([barcode.getBarcodeType isEqualToString:str]){
                     [self validBarcodeFound:barcode];
                     return;
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
}


- (void) validBarcodeFound:(Barcode *)barcode{ 

    [self stopRunning];
    [self.foundBarcodes addObject:barcode];   

    NSString *input = [barcode getBarcodeData];
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long) [self.foundBarcodes count]-1];

    if ([input length] >= 13)
    {
        input = [input substringToIndex:12];
    }

    loadUrl = [[@"http://www.mywebsite.com/" stringByAppendingString:input] stringByAppendingString:@"?utm_source=iphone"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toWebControl" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Why all the `[super viewDidLoad]` calls? That should only be called from inside `viewDidLoad`? You also need to show more code I think. i.e. What calls `validateBarcodeFound` and when? I would perhaps move your request code to `viewWillAppear` so you know your UI is fully setup.

Comment: make sure you perform your segue in the main queue. I see your async request callback is performing on a separate NSOperationQueue, so you need to `dispatch_async` to `dispatch_get_main_queue` the code that performing a segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always perform a segue in the main queue. Your callback is executing in the separate `NSOperationQueue`, you need to wrap `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,...`.

Plus, as @rory-mckinnel mentioned in the comments, remove unnecessary `[super viewDidLoad]` calls as in may lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Swift, I was using:

```
shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any)
```

Instead of:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any)
```